# PHP Search Form display incorrectly?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, search

Here I have a Search Form and the PHP search code, I just cant seem to get the problem. Well the problem I am having is that I have a For Sale Page and a For Rent Page, when I use the search form it displays the properties but it display all the properties from the For Sale Page and the For Rent Page.
If I select the For Sale option then it needs to display all the properties that are For Sale and the same goes for the For Rent.

```
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="searchmodule clearfix" data-effect="slide-right">
                        <form id="advanced_search" action="search.php" class="clearfix" name="advanced_search" method="post">

                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                <label for="type"><b>Type</b></label>
<select name="type">
<option value=""></option>
  <option value="House">House</option>
  <option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
  <option value="Flat">Flat</option>
  <option value="Townhouse">Townhouse</option>
  <option value="Plot">Plot</option>
  <option value="Farm">Farm</option>
</select>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                <label for="status"><b>Status</b></label>

<select name="status">
<option value=""></option>
  <option value="For Sale">For Sale</option>
  <option value="For Rent">For Rent</option>
</select>

                            </div>


                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                <label for="bedrooms"><b>Bedrooms</b></label>
<select name="bedrooms">
<option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                <label for="baths"><b>Bathrooms</b></label>
<select name="baths">
<option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>


                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                <label for="min_price"><b>Min Price</b></label>

<select name="min_price">
<option value=""></option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="2000">2000</option>
  <option value="3000">3000</option>
  <option value="4000">4000</option>
  <option value="5000">5000</option>
  <option value="6000">6000</option>
  <option value="7000">7000</option>
  <option value="8000">8000</option>
  <option value="9000">9000</option>
  <option value="10000">10000</option>
</select>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                <label for="max_price"><b>Max Price</b></label>
<select name="max_price">
<option value=""></option>
  <option value="100000">100000</option>
  <option value="200000">200000</option>
  <option value="300000">300000</option>
  <option value="400000">400000</option>
  <option value="500000">500000</option>
  <option value="600000">600000</option>
  <option value="700000">700000</option>
  <option value="800000">800000</option>
  <option value="900000">900000</option>
  <option value="1000000">1000000</option>
</select>

                            </div>

                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <button name="search" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SEARCH PROPERTY</button>
```

I am still kind of new to the whole PHP and MySQL so please help me right.

Here I have the PHP Coding for the Search, the problem is here somewhere and I just don't know what:

```
     <?php
                   include 'database.php';
                   $pdo = Database::connect();
                     $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                   $sql = "SELECT  * FROM properties INNER JOIN images ON images.propertyid = properties.propertyid WHERE Status ='For Sale' OR Status = 'For Rent' GROUP BY images.propertyid";



                   foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {

             $propertyid =   $row['PropertyId'];
                 $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM images where PropertyId = ?";
        $q1 = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
        $q1->execute(array($propertyid));
        $data = $q1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


$type = $_POST['type'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$minprice = $_POST['min_price'];
$maxprice = $_POST['max_price'];
$bedrooms = $_POST['bedrooms'];
$baths = $_POST['baths'];


if ($status != ''){
 $qStatus = " AND status = '$status' ";
 $sql = $sql . $qStatus;
}
if ($type != ''){
$qType = " AND type = '$type' ";
$sql = $sql . $qType;
}
if ($baths != ''){
$qBaths = " AND baths = '$baths' ";
$sql = $sql . $qBaths;
}
if ($bedrooms != ''){
$qBedrooms = " AND bedrooms = '$bedrooms' ";
$sql = $sql . $qBedrooms;
}
if ($minprice != ''){
$qMinprice = " AND min_price = '$minprice' ";
$sql = $sql . $qMinprice;
}
if ($maxprice != ''){
$qMaxprice = " AND max_price = '$maxprice' ";
$sql = $sql . $qMaxprice;
}
$sql = $sql." GROUP BY PropertyId";


if ($status == 'For Sale'){


           echo '<li class="col-md-4">';

                            echo '<div class="proj_block">';
                            echo '<img alt="" style="opacity: 1" src="'. $row['ImageUrl'].'"></div>';
                            echo '<div class="proj_descr"><h2>'. $row['Title'] . '</h2>';
                            echo '<div class="proj_descr_txt">'.'<b>Location: </b> '. $row['Location'] . '</div>';
                            echo '<div class="proj_descr_txt">'.'<b>Bed: </b> '. $row['Bedrooms'] . '</div>';
                            echo '<div class="proj_descr_txt">'.'<b>Bath: </b> '. $row['Bathrooms'] . '</div>';
                            echo '<div class="proj_descr_txt">'.'<b>Parking: </b> '. $row['Parking'] . '</div>';
                            echo '<div class="proj_descr_txt">'.'<b>Price: </b>R'. $row['Price'] . '</div>';
                            echo '<a href="readmore.php?PropertyId='.$row['PropertyId'].'">Read More</a>';

                            echo '</li>';


}


else if ($status == 'For Rent'){


echo '<li class="col-md-4">';

                            echo '<div class="proj_block">';
                            echo '<img alt="" style="opacity: 1" src="'. $row['ImageUrl'].'"></div>';
                            echo '<div class="proj_descr"><h2>'. $row['Title'] . '</h2>';
                            echo '<div class="proj_descr_txt">'.'<b>Location: </b> '. $row['Location'] . '</div>';
                            echo '<div class="proj_descr_txt">'.'<b>Bed: </b> '. $row['Bedrooms'] . '</div>';
                            echo '<div class="proj_descr_txt">'.'<b>Bath: </b> '. $row['Bathrooms'] . '</div>';
                            echo '<div class="proj_descr_txt">'.'<b>Parking: </b> '. $row['Parking'] . '</div>';
                            echo '<div class="proj_descr_txt">'.'<b>Price: </b>R'. $row['Price'] . '</div>';
                            echo '<a href="readmore.php?PropertyId='.$row['PropertyId'].'">Read More</a>';

                            echo '</li>';

        }
        }
                   Database::disconnect();
                  ?>
```

Comment: What kind of join do you need?

Comment: Replace `$data['ImageUrl']` with `$row['ImageUrl']`.

Comment: What is ur exact requirement ? There are different types of join for tables? and regarding ur error you should make an if check if the image is available in ur db or not ? If it is not den show a default no image pic and when image is available show the saved img, you can use the isset function in php to check .

Comment: Daan you see like I said I am kind of new to this so I don't know hahaha

Comment: I have tried to replace it it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a LEFT JOIN like this :

```
SELECT * FROM PROPERTIES as Prop
LEFT JOIN Images as Img
ON Img.PropertyId = Prop.PropertyId
WHERE **** Your condition ****
ORDER BY ** (DESC or ASC)
```

Comment: I have tried this LEFT JOIN it works but it duplicate it like alot of times and the I still get this error: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\wamp\www\sa property
finder\search.php on line 66

Comment: but when I change the $data to $row then the images display but also duplicated alot?

Comment: Can you add a picture?

Comment: if you want to avoid duplicate lines you can use a simple group by.